# URLに立てたフラッグによって条件分岐するsmartyの記述をお教え願います。

Tags: smarty

お世話になっております。初歩的で恐縮ですがどうかアドバイスをお願い致します。

URLに立てたフラッグによって条件分岐する記述はPHPでは以下の用になりますが、同様のケースをsmartyで記述する場合どのような記述になるかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

if($_GET['id'] == '1')  {
                 a;
} else if($_GET['id'] == '2')  {
                 b;
} else if($_GET['id'] == '3')  {
c;

Answer (score 1):

Viewの性質上、PHP側で変数に代入して、smarty側はその変数を見て分けるべきかなと思います。

どうしてもやるなら、{php}タグで埋め込めば良いかと思います。